# SQL Math Equation with subqueries

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, addition

I'm sitting on a DB2 server, trying to calculate a KPI card.   It's a fairly simple equation..

Revenue this year + budget rest of year /  Total Budget

But whenever i start dividing i get 1 as result.   What am I overlooking?   I have tried different approaches. and the below had my higest hopes :-D

```
select ((x.Rev+ y.Budget) / t.Budget)
from
(
        select sum(oms) as Rev from vislib.faktura
        Where Origin = 'MOVEX'
        AND yy = 2021
        AND SMCD = '2294'
        AND IVNO <> 0
) x
join
(
       select sum(TASTBUDOMS) as Budget  from vislib.faktura
        where ORIGIN = 'TASTBUD'
        AND yy = 2021
        AND MM > 3
        AND SMCD = '2294'
) y on 1=1
join
(
       select sum(TASTBUDOMS) as Budget from vislib.faktura
        where ORIGIN = 'TASTBUD'
        AND yy = 2021
        AND SMCD = '2294'
) t on 1=1
```

Comment: integer division? Try multiply by `1.0` before division.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation to get the values you want:

```
select sum(case when Origin = 'MOVEX' and ivno <> 0 then oms end) as Rev,
       sum(case when Origin = 'TASTBUD' and mm > 3 then TASTBUDOMS end) as budget,
       sum(case when Origin = 'TASTBUD' then TASTBUDOMS end) as budget2      
from vislib.faktura
Where yy = 2021 and
      SMCD = '2294'
```

You can then combine these:

```
select ( (sum(case when Origin = 'MOVEX' and ivno <> 0 then oms end) +
          sum(case when Origin = 'TASTBUD' and mm > 3 then TASTBUDOMS end)
         ) /
         sum(case when Origin = 'TASTBUD' then TASTBUDOMS end)
       ) as ratio      
from vislib.faktura
Where yy = 2021 and
      SMCD = '2294'
```

Comment: But this gives 3 results?   I thougth that was, what i was doing.  Conditional aggregation.   Could i se a simple example, to understand where i’m off?

Comment: @MikeSeisbye . . . This returns three columns.  It is an example of conditional aggregation.

Comment: Sorry.. I still don't understand how i'm going to close this?  I just want 1 result.  not three.  so how to a go about getting the result to be (rev + bud) / Bud2 ?

Comment: @MikeSeisbye . . . Just divide the expressions.